# Expression GreaterThanOrEqual method error

Tags: c#, expression

I'v built a static class and try to realize dynamic query with generic params. Below is my interface definition and class definition:

```
public interface IRangeValue<T> where T : struct
{
    Nullable<T> High{get;set;}
    Nullable<T> Low { get; set; }
}

public class DataRangeT<T> : IRangeValue<T>
    where T : struct
{
    Nullable<T> _high;
    Nullable<T> _low;
    public Nullable<T> High { get { return _high; } set { _high = value; } }
    public Nullable<T> Low { get { return _low; } set { _low = value; } }

}
```

then, I built a static method to realize dynamic query:

```
public static class ExpressionHelperT<K>
    where K : struct
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> RangeCompare<T>(Expression<Func<T, K>> selector, IRangeValue<K> patten)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
        if (patten.High.HasValue)
        {
            predicate = predicate.And<T>(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.LessThanOrEqual(selector, Expression.Constant(patten.High.Value, typeof(K)))));
        }
        if (patten.Low.HasValue)
        {
            predicate = predicate.And<T>(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(selector, Expression.Constant(patten.Low.Value, typeof(K)))));
        }
        return predicate;
    }

}
```

the method And is defined like below:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
```

Now, I try to test my `RangeCompare<T>` method, I invoke the method like below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataRangeT<DateTime> dataRange = new DataRangeT<DateTime>();

        dataRange.High = null;
        dataRange.Low = DateTime.Today;

        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2018, 1, 1));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2018, 2, 1));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2018, 3, 1));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2018, 4, 1));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2018, 5, 1));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2018, 6, 1));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2018, 7, 1));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2018, 8, 1));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2018, 9, 1));

        List<DateTime> results = dates.Where<DateTime>(ExpressionHelperT<DateTime>.RangeCompare<DateTime>(c => c.Date, dataRange)).ToList();

        foreach (DateTime dt in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But compliter always told me GreaterThanOrEqual error, no such binary operator definition between System.Func`2[System.DateTime,System.DateTime]” and “System.DateTime”.
This error display at below:

```
predicate = predicate.And<T>(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(selector, Expression.Constant(patten.Low.Value, typeof(K)))));
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler is in fact correct: You are trying to perform a `>=` between a lambda and a number:

```
Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(selector /* this is a lambda*/, Expression.Constant(...))
```

I really think you should try to avoid nested lambdas as much as possible. The best way to achieve this (imho) is to replace the parameter expressions in the second lambda by corresponding parameters of the first lambda and then merge the bodies of the two lambda expressions like so:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var replacer = new ParameterReplaceVisitor(expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, replacer.Visit(expr2.Body)),
            expr1.Parameters[0]);
    }

    private class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private ParameterExpression _oldParameter;
        private ParameterExpression _newParameter;

        public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression oldParameter, ParameterExpression newParameter)
        {
            _oldParameter = oldParameter;
            _newParameter = newParameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (node == _oldParameter)
            {
                return _newParameter;
            }
            else
            {
                return node;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** An advantage of this solution that avoids lambdas is that a Linq implementation is likely to understand what you wanted to do and translate that e.g. to SQL. I am not sure that for instance EF would try to translate lambda expression invocations to SQL because it is unlikely that this actually works.